# Initializing NSOpenGLPixelFormat in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, swift, nsopenglview

Apparently I'm the only one to attempt this, as none of my Google searches turned up anything helpful. Assume I'm initializing an attribute array like this:

```
let glPFAttributes = [
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 48,
    NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 16,
    NSOpenGLPFAMultisample,
    NSOpenGLPFASampleBuffers, 1,
    NSOpenGLPFASamples, 4,
    NSOpenGLPFAMinimumPolicy,
    0
]
```

These things are all regular Ints, I've checked. Now if I do

```
let glPixelFormat = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: glPFAttributes)
```

the compiler gives me this error message:

> 'Int' is not identical to 'NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute'

If I made a mistake somewhere, I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute` is `typeAlias` of `UInt32`. `NSOpenGLPixelFormat` intializer takes array of `NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute` so you need to make array and convert all `Int` to `UInt32`.Below code will work

```
let glPFAttributes:[NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute] = [
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAColorSize), UInt32(48),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize), UInt32(16),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAMultisample),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFASampleBuffers), UInt32(1),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFASamples), UInt32(4),
    UInt32(NSOpenGLPFAMinimumPolicy),
    UInt32(0)
]


let glPixelFormat = NSOpenGLPixelFormat(attributes: glPFAttributes)
```